# Java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException JApplet/HTML

Tags: java, html, japplet

Ok so this is my first applet, I tried many times to bypass this Exception.
Any sort of help would be really appreciated! Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
package Application;

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FirstApplet extends JApplet
{
    private JPanel jpnlMain = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private JPanel jpnlBoutton = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,5));
    private JPanel jpnlLogo = new JSplash(this);
    private GenericRoundedButton[] jbtnAllo = new GenericRoundedButton[10];

    public void init(){
        super.init();
        this.add(jpnlMain);
        for(int i =0;i<jbtnAllo.length;i++){
            jbtnAllo[i] = new GenericRoundedButton();
            jpnlBoutton.add(jbtnAllo[i]);
        }       
        jpnlMain.add(jpnlBoutton,"North");
        jpnlMain.add(jpnlLogo,"Center");
    }
}
```

And here is My HTML Code:

```
<html>
    <title>The ImageDemo applet</title>
    <hr>
        <applet code="Application.FirstApplet.class" width="400" height="400">
    </applet>
    <hr>
</html>
```

Comment: JSplash is a class that extends JPanel and is only there to show an Image for a couple of miliseconds

GenericRoundedButton is a Class that redo the Button so that they have round edges.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Copy/paste the exception text so we can see which line causes it.

Comment: *"this is my first applet"*  Why even make an applet?  Code the GUI as a frame and launch it from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: Well basicaly, i did an Applet for work we are trying to make a User interface for a Switch wich would be accessable from the internet and the user could control the switch from a port. Thank you for your comment i will check Java Web start! Looks like it could be really usefull!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code (an SSCCE that is very close to your code) loads without showing any exceptions.  I can conclude from that, that the problem lies in the parts of the code you chose **not to include.**

```
// <applet code=FirstApplet width=400 height=400></applet>
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FirstApplet extends JApplet
{
    private JPanel jpnlMain = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private JPanel jpnlBoutton = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,5));
    private JPanel jpnlLogo = new JPanel();
    private JButton[] jbtnAllo = new JButton[10];

    public void init(){
        super.init();
        this.add(jpnlMain);
        for(int i =0;i<jbtnAllo.length;i++){
            jbtnAllo[i] = new JButton();
            jpnlBoutton.add(jbtnAllo[i]);
        }
        jpnlMain.add(jpnlBoutton,"North");
        jpnlMain.add(jpnlLogo,"Center");
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the error and it was in the part that i did not include thank you for your help! I was basically using an object from the class java.awt.Robot so i just changed a bit my code and its now working perfectly!